# How to make a composite key in mssql?

Tags: sql, composite-key

I want to create a composite key in mssql. e.g. {address(city, state, zipcode)}.

I'm new to sql. I want to know if there is an exact syntax for creating a composite key in a table. I've seen a similar question and the answer was creating the columns and adding a unique constraint to those columns. However, i dont know if this solves my problem.

the code could be something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee(
SSN INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
FirstName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
City NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
State NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
ZipCode INT NOT NULL
);
```

I guess there is no problem using 3 different keys for address like this. However, I want to know if there is a better solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Composite key of what? PS SSN as a key might cause issues. Means the person entering the data has to know it before they can. Also if an error is made and they want to edit it, could cause problems with any referenced tables.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson as i gave an example; composite key would be address in this scenario. Also making SSN the pk is not main thing here, it was just an example. What im asking is how to make address a composite key that consist of city, state and zipcode

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't advice to have key with that triple, since it can happen to have multiple Employees with the same triple City, State and ZipCode.
Anyway, if you want to have a unique constraint, do the following:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee(
SSN INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
FirstName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
City NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
State NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
ZipCode INT NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT address UNIQUE(City, State, ZipCode)
);
```

With this, you are ensuring that City, State and ZipCode are unique for all the rows in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Key plays an important role in relational database; it is used for identifying unique rows from table. It also establishes relationship among tables.

- In your case using a composite key will not help for the table you
        are creating. Since multiple SSN can have the same City, ZipCode,
        State as input.
- I would suggest to use another table as Address and have these
  columns unique there.
- It would be more helpful if you state your requirement(what you are
  going to do with these keys).